# Unload jquery ui dialog completely

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Im using

```
$('#test').dialog('destroy');
```

but it seems to leave some auto created elements on the page, I need to remove all possible elements which the dialog has hanging around in the dom, is this possible?

Comment: What elements does it leave around by example? Reading the docs it sounds like it's does a full cleanup.

Comment: hmm thats what I thought it does but I have a few iframes left on the page, Ill check again to confirm they are in fact being added by t he dialogs

Comment: what its doing is moving the dialog divs outside of the container div that the started in the dom. I was expecting them to still be within the container div after destroy

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, when recreating dialogs, the elements in the old dialog appeared not to have been destroyed.

solution is to wipe the dialog contents clean on close:

```
$("<div>someelements</div>").dialog({
    title:"sometitle", 
    close: function() {$(this).html("");}
})
```